ArgoCD not creating namespaces even when "CreateNamespace=true" option enabled
here is my app of apps:
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: my-app-of-apps
  namespace: argocd
  finalizers:
    - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
spec:
  project: default
  source:
    repoURL: https://github.com/cooervo/kubernetes-examples.git
    targetRevision: HEAD
    path: 11-argocd-app-of-apps-sync-waves-istio/apps/
  destination:
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: true
      selfHeal: true
      allowEmpty: true
    syncOptions:
      - PruneLast=true
      - CreateNamespace=true
      - PrunePropagationPolicy=foreground
    retry:
      limit: 2
      

and the child istio base app:
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: istio-base-application
  namespace: argocd
  finalizers:
    - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
spec:
  project: default
 defaultRevision=default
  source:
    repoURL: https://istio-release.storage.googleapis.com/charts
    chart: base
    helm:
      parameters:
        - name: defaultRevision
          value: "default"
      namespace: istio-system
    targetRevision: 1.20.0
  destination:
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
    namespace: istio-system
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: true
      selfHeal: true
      allowEmpty: true
    syncOptions:
      - PruneLast=true
      - CreateNamespace=true
      - PrunePropagationPolicy=foreground
    retry:
      limit: 2  


Yet I keep getting error:
SyncFailed namespaces "istio-system" not found

Here's the public github repo just in case

Which ArgoCD version? Is ArgoCD installed cluster wide? Did you check ArgoCD logs, they might contain useful info.

Your configuration looks correct. If you were making child app config gradually, try deleting it from the repo first, making ArgoCD delete it and then re-add.
If you added - CreateNamespace=true when child app was already known to Argo, it will keep failing regardless what you do. Even if you remove it from Argo dashboard manually, root app will get same error when re-syncing. But if you remove and then re-add - should be fine.
